# How do I use this regular expression? (Aweber Email Parser)

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to use this **Regular Expression** which Aweber provides for **email parsing.**

I'm supposed to be able to send an email to aweber, with this ruleset, and aweber will add the email to my list.

Here is the rule:

```
Trigger Rule:    From:[^\n|.]+user\@domain\.com | MATCH HEADERS
Rule 1:          \n[>\s]*Email:\s+(.+?)\n       | MATCH BODY
Rule 2:          \n[>\s]*Name:\s+(.+?)\n        | MATCH BODY
```

Does anyone know how this works? What format does the regular expression expect to receive?

Thank you soooo much for your help!

Best,
Nick

Comment: Are you sure that all the characters in that are correct? I don't recognize the "[>\s]". Maybe or you meant "[^\s]"? (Or, maybe I'm about to learn a new regex trick myself when someone responds)

Comment: I think the "[>\s]" is just either a ">" or a space, for quoted replies like, "> > > > Email: ..."

Comment: @Aaron: D'oh! That's exactly it. I was thinking too complex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your answer to my comment above doesn't substantively change the intent:

```
Trigger Rule:    From:[^\n|.]+user\@domain\.com | MATCH HEADERS
# Match "From:" and "user@domain.com" all on the same line

Rule 1:          \n[>\s]*Email:\s+(.+?)\n       | MATCH BODY
#Match "<<beginning of line>> <<some white space, or maybe not>> "Email:" <<some white space, but maybe more>> <<anything and everything until the end of the line>>

Rule 2:          \n[>\s]*Name:\s+(.+?)\n        | MATCH BODY
#Match "<<beginning of line>> <<some white space, or maybe not>> "Name:" <<some white space, but maybe more>> <<anything and everything until the end of the line>>
```

Edit:

The lines marked `"<<some white space, or maybe not>>"` should be `"<<some white space, or several ">" characters, or maybe none of these>>`

Comment: I still don't understand. Kindly explain further. Thanks!

Comment: Well ... what part doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: When I click on the "Test Parser Before Saving". it always says: "no rulesets were matched". This is what I type in:

From: test@mydomain.com
Email: TestEmail@email.com
Name: John Doe

It keeps on saying "No rulesets were matched."